# Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I'm not able to launch IE browser to run my selenium automated tests written in Java. I'm using Windows 7 and IE 9. Below is my code:

Please find the attachment.[image]

```
public class GoogleNews {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl;
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver =new InternetExplorerDriver();
        baseUrl = "https://news.google.co.in/";

    }

    @Test
    public void testApple() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you copy and paste the code here ?

Comment: I'm getting this message in the console - "Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
2.30.0.0
Listening on port 27576"

Comment: The above one is a Info Message. After receiving that what happens?

Comment: Manigandan - browser is not opening.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 1.18 seconds
Build info: version: '2.30.0', revision: 'dc1ef9c', time: '2013-02-19 00:15:57'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'

Answer (score 149, accepted):

It needs to set same Security level in all zones. To do that follow the steps below:

1. Open IE
2. Go to Tools -> Internet Options -> Security
3. Set all zones (Internet, Local intranet, Trusted sites, Restricted sites) to the same protected mode, enabled or disabled should not matter.

Finally, set Zoom level to 100% by right clicking on the gear located at the top right corner and enabling the status-bar.
Default zoom level is now displayed at the lower right.

Comment: I still don't see it working for me. I'm with Win7 and IEDriverServer_x64_2.43.0 and getting this error even after following your instructions. Error is "org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer."

Comment: Go through this link : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/automation-using-internet-explorer-11-pritam-maske

Comment: Enterprise security often doesn't allow you to change the default security levels for all zones. Doing so might make your system vulnerable to attacks. Setting `IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings` to true is the right way to do this. See my answer below.

Answer (score 20):

Well as the stack trace says, you would need to set the protected mode settings to same for all zones in IE.  Read the why here : http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.in/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html

and a quick how to from the same link  : "In IE, from the Tools menu (or the gear icon in the toolbar in later versions), select "Internet options." Go to the Security tab. At the bottom of the dialog for each zone, you should see a check box labeled "Enable Protected Mode." Set the value of the check box to the same value, either checked or unchecked, for each zone"

Comment: +1. Much better answer than the accepted, because linked blog post  explains WHY - and why you should set all zones as protected (accepted answer might mislead you to turn protected mode off)

Answer (score 13):

The following snippet of WebDriver Java code should work to launch IE. The code will ignore the setup of Protected mode settings for all zone in the IE browser.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
File file = new File("D:\\Ripon Al Wasim\\IEDriverServer.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Download IEDriverServer and extract it into your desired location and set the absolute path (In my above example it was "D:\Ripon Al Wasim\IEDriverServer.exe")

Comment: DO NOT use INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS.  It is a hack to allow people to run tests in a locked down environment where they are unable to configure the browser correctly.  Using this setting will generate random failures and general instability.  It should NEVER be used as a matter of course.

Comment: Using the above code does not need to configure the same level (Enabled/Disabled) for Protected Mode settings for all zones.

Comment: I accidentally used INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS
in my code. How do i disable it now?

Answer (score 4):

**Rather than using Absolute path for IEDriverServer.exe, its better to use relative path in accordance to the project.**

```
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
        capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
        File fil = new File("iDrivers\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", fil.getAbsolutePath());
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);        
        driver.get("https://www.irctc.co.in");
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `IE->Tools->Internet Options`.
2. Go to Security tab.
3. Either Enable/Disable the protected mode for all(Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted Sites & Restricted Sites.)

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to share the actual code as few might still be confused about how to implement it.This is for C# NUNIT implementation. You need to do this because your company might not allow you to change the default security settings for obvious reasons. Good luck!

```
InternetExplorerOptions options = new InternetExplorerOptions();
            options.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;
            options.IgnoreZoomLevel = true;
            driver = new
                InternetExplorerDriver("C:\\Users\\stdd\\Desktop\\SLL\\SLLAutomation" +
                "\\Clysis\\STGSearch\\STGClaSearch\\Driver\\", options);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Answer (score 2):

For NighwatchJS use:

```
"ie" : {
  "desiredCapabilities": {
    "browserName": "internet explorer",
    "javascriptEnabled": true,
    "acceptSslCerts": true,
    "allowBlockedContent": true,
    "ignoreProtectedModeSettings": true
  }
},
```

Comment: the `ignoreProtectedModeSettings` helped me; i don't have admin and i could not change the Protected mode in IE Settings.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue you have to do two things :

1. You will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that
   the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet
   Explorer it creates.
2. Change few settings of Internet Explorer browser on that machine
       (where you desire to run automation).

**1 . Setting Registry Key / Entry :**

- To set registry key or entry, you need to open "Registry Editor".
- To open "Registry Editor" press windows button key + r alphabet key
  which will open "Run Window" and then type "regedit" and press enter.
- Or Press Windows button key and enter "regedit" at start menu and
  press enter. Now depending upon your OS type whether 32/64 bit follow
  the corresponding steps.

**Windows 32 bit :** 
go to this location - "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl" and check for "FEATURE_BFCACHE" key.

**Windows 64 bit :** 
go to this location - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl and check for "FEATURE_BFCACHE" key.
**Please note that** the **FEATURE_BFCACHE** subkey may or may not be present, and **should be created** if it is not present.

**Important:** Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

[image: Registry Setting]

**2 . Change Settings of Internet Explorer Browser :**

- Click on setting button and select **"Internet options"**.
- On "Internet options" window go to **"Security"** tab
- Now select **"Internet"** option and unchecked the "Enable Protected Mode" check box and change the "Security level" to low.
- Now select **"Local Intranet"** Option and change the "Security level" to low.
- Now select **"Trusted Sites"** Option and change the "Security level" to low.

[image: Internet Options]

- Now click on **"Apply"** button , a warning pop up may appear click on "OK" button for warning and then on "OK" button on Internet Options window.

[image: Save Settings]

- After this restart the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to modify the protected mode settings manually on my system since they were disabled. But the below VBA snippet for updating the registry values did the trick for me.(Please be cautious about any restrictions on your organization on modifying registry, before trying this)

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
strComputer = "."

Set ScriptMe=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

'Disable protected mode for local intranet'
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1\"
strValueName = "2500"
dwValue = 0
ScriptMe.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

'Disable protected mode for trusted pages'
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\2\"
strValueName = "2500"
dwValue = 0
ScriptMe.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

'Disable protected mode for internet'
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3\"
strValueName = "2500"
dwValue = 0
ScriptMe.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

'Disable protected mode for restricted sites'
strKeyPath = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\4\"
strValueName = "2500"
dwValue = 0
ScriptMe.SetDWORDValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER,strKeyPath,strValueName,dwValue

msgbox "Protected Mode Settings are updated"
```

Just copy paste the above code into notepad and save it with .vbs extension and double click it!

Now try running your automation script again

Answer (score 0):

### Before you start with Internet Explorer and Selenium Webdriver Consider these two important rules.

- The zoom level :Should be set to default (100%) and
- The security zone settings : Should be same for all. The security settings should be set according to your organisation permissions.

### How to set this?

- Simply go to Internet explorer, do both the stuffs manually. Thats it. No secret.
- Do it through your code.

**Method 1**:

DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

```
    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.33.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);


    driver.get(baseURl);

    //Identify your elements and go ahead testing...
```

This will definetly **not show any error and browser will open** and also will navigate to the URL.

BUT This **will not identify any element** and hence you can not proceed.

Why? Because we have simly suppressed the error and asked IE to open and get that URL. However Selenium will identify elements only if the browser zoom is 100% ie. default.
So the final code would be

**Method 2 The robust and full proof way**:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

    capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","D:\\IEDriverServer_Win32_2.33.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");

    WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);


    driver.get(baseURl);

    driver.findElement(By.tagName("html")).sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"0"));

    //Identify your elements and go ahead testing...
```

Hope this helps. Do let me know if further information is required.