# Why Firefox Selenium driver doesn't have "UnhandledAlertException"

Tags: java, ruby, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium and was trying to handle Popups on different browsers like IE and Firefox.

In case of IE, if we don't set the capability - "unexpectedAlertBehaviour" to "ignore" the driver will throw an "UnhandledAlertException" and accepts the popup by default. Though we can change this behavior in Capabilities.

```
cap = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.ie(:ignoreProtectedModeSettings=>true,:ignoreZoomSetting=>true,:unexpectedAlertBehaviour=>"ignore")
```

But In case of FF, Capability - "unexpectedAlertBehaviour" is not available and the only capability related to handling popups is handlesAlerts - which is also a read only capability.

```
cap = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox(:unexpectedAlertBehaviour=>"ignore")
```

The FF driver doesn't throws UnhandledAlertException and handles alerts by it self.

**

How I can handle unexpected alerts in case of Firefox?

**

Comment: you have created an `ie` object. Not a `Firefox`.

Comment: Yes that is an example for IE.., I need something similar to that for FF...

Comment: If you want to work with Firefox, create an Firefox instance, not an ie one

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I have an fire fox instance created. I have updated the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984997/selenium-ruby-binding-capabilities-documentation

Comment: @ErkiM, Thanks for the link. Its one of my post. Here the question is why firefox doesn't have UnhandledAlertException and why it has only one read only capability for alert handling i.e. handlesAlerts.

Comment: @Prasant, Sry, I no nothing of Ruby bindings.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capability.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, 
                         UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
Firefox driver = new FirefoxDriver(capability);
```