# Vaadin TestBench Tests in IE11: NoSuchWindowException

Tags: java, selenium, vaadin, test-bench

I try to run Vaadin TestBench tests on IE11 32bit.

I already found this thread: [Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java/34723165?noredirect=1#comment57192026_34723165) but it didn't help me. I still see this error after running my test case for IE11:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser 
    (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 19 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.44.0', 
    revision:'76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
    System info: host: 'isa-050', ip: '192.168.100.14', os.name: 'Windows 7',  
    os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_66'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true,
    ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal,     
    ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, 
    version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, 
    ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, 
    ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, 
    browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:29878/, 
    takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, 
    ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, 
    cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: 61623ee3-9a3a-4cc9-96d0-d9d8202647d1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:508)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.commands.TestBenchCommandExecutor.waitForVaadin(TestBenchCommandExecutor.java:133)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1._d65waitForVaadin(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.invoke(DriverInvocationHandler.java:62)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1.waitForVaadin(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1.java)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.waitForVaadinIfNecessary(DriverInvocationHandler.java:78)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.DriverInvocationHandler.invoke(DriverInvocationHandler.java:48)
    at com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1.getKeyboard(TestBenchDriverProxy_$$_jvst375_1.java)
    at org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.<init>(Actions.java:41)
    at test_project.Testfaelle.findeTabellenElement(Testfaelle.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

This is my test case:

```
   @Test
   public void findeTabellenElement(){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\amustroph\\Desktop\\IEDriverServer.exe"); 
                //DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
                //capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true); 
                //WebDriver driver1 = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
                //setDriver(driver1);

                setDriver(new InternetExplorerDriver());

                try {
                    getDriver().get("http://localhost:8080/MavenVaadinHelloWorld");
                    Thread.sleep(7000);
                    Actions action = new Actions(getDriver());
                    WebElement w1 = findElement(By.className("v-table-caption-container"));
                    action.moveToElement(w1).click().perform();
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    action.moveToElement(w1).click().perform();
                    Thread.sleep(10000);

                    WebElement table = $(TableElement.class).get(0);
                    action.moveToElement(table).perform();
                    Thread.sleep(7000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                getDriver().quit();
}
```

I also add a picture of my IE config. Maybe I forgot anything?

[image: IE config]

Do you have any idea?

Comment: can you try with IE 64bit driver and using IE64 -bit..few days back i remember i had seen a known issue in IE32 bit webdriver

Comment: Thank you, I tried but it's still not working.

Comment: ohh i forgot to check ur ie security settings...as u can see ur restricted sites setting is set to high but all other are set to medium..turn all of them off or turn them ON and keep all at same level

Comment: Ok... I had to drive all sliders to highest degree because our administration allows only "high" fort he last zone. I activated Javascript for all zones. And ....moment.... it didn't help-I got the same error again,

Comment: ok..tell me ur complete configuration like IE 11 version, 32/64 bit, selenium version, platform and other details then i'll try to replicate it

Comment: We use VaadinTestbench 4.1.0, IE 11.0.9600 (Error reproduced on 32 and 64bit version),18124 on Windows 7 Professional 64bit. My Test Case is implemented in Eclipse "Java EE IDE for Web Developers". Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1). in Java 8.

Comment: i'll give it a shot today and get back to you

Comment: That's nice. Thanks a lot!