# Why the ignoreProtectedModeSettings of the IE driver allows to find elements by id with Protractor?

Tags: selenium, protractor

I'm learning Protractor by making a very simple test:

```
describe('Tick Tack Toe game', function() {
  it('marks positions as played', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('file:///C:/Users/potero/angular/Angular_TickTackToe/ticktacktoe.html');
    var p00 = element(by.id("p00"));
    p00.click();
    expect(p00.getText()).toEqual("X");
  });
});
```

This test passed in Chrome almost effortlessly. But I also have to test on IE so I added the necessary lines to my protractor conf file which ended up like this:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs : [ '../specs/**/*.protractorspec.js' ],
    multiCapabilities: [{
          'browserName': 'internet explorer'
        }, {
          'browserName': 'chrome'
        }]
};
```

Chrome kept passing the test but IE could not be launched due to its protected mode settings being different for every zone. I made them equal, which I read on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java). Then IE was launched but the test failed cause IE could not find the element with id p00 (check my spec above). By reading the error output on the console I saw the property of the IE selenium driver called "ignoreProtectedModeSettings" which was set to false. This got my attention so I reset the protected mode settings in IE and added a line to my protractor conf file, which ended up like this:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs : [ '../specs/**/*.protractorspec.js' ],
    multiCapabilities: [{
          'browserName': 'internet explorer',
          'ignoreProtectedModeSettings': true
        }, {
          'browserName': 'chrome'
        }]
};
```

And the IE test passed. Every time I ran it. So, why does a property that has to do with security settings allow me to find elements by id using Protractor selectors?

Answer (score 2):

Background on Protected Mode

Internet Explorer’s Protected Mode is a security sandbox that relies upon the integrity level system in Windows. A process may have only one integrity level (IL), so if you navigate an IE instance between a Internet (Protected Mode, LowIL) and Intranet (non-Protected Mode, MediumIL) site, Internet Explorer must handle the navigation in a new process. In IE7 on Vista, this was very visible—a new browser window would open automatically. In IE8, with the introduction of Loosely-Coupled IE (LCIE), we can handle this more subtly.

You can find more information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/03/internet-explorer-automation-protected-mode-lcie-default-integrity-level-medium.aspx