# how to change IE internet security settings using nightwatch.js

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js, saucelabs

I just learned that the reason why my website forces you to re login whenever you navigate the site using a nightwatch test is because of an internet security setting in the saucelabs IE driver. Is there a way to change the IE driver security setting using nightwatch.js configuration/code? I need to set the security setting on the IE driver to medium low.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you **can't** control this via Nightwatch or via WebDriver (and the workarounds may do [more harm than good](http://jimevansmusic.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/youre-doing-it-wrong-protected-mode-and.html)).

You need to fix it at the Registry-level (e.g. [via a script](http://automationoverflow.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/registry-entries-for-internet-explorer.html)), or manually at the IE-level, e.g: [Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java)

That's not much help for Sauce Labs. I haven't found documentation on enabling any similar kind of workaround (not too surprisingly).

Perhaps your best bet is to test this locally while the developers work to resolve the underlying problem.