# Selenium in C# when run the test case with IE browser

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm researching selenium webdriver in `C#`. When I run the test case to test browser `IE`, then this error:

> Test method AgileTravelUITests.GoogleSearchTest.TestIE threw
>   exception:  OpenQA.Selenium.DriverServiceNotFoundException: The
>   IEDriverServer.exe file does not exist in the current directory or in
>   a directory on the PATH environment variable. The driver can be
>   downloaded at
>   http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html.

I tried download and install `2.53` folder with `IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0.zip`, but this didn't work.

This is my code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestIE()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

    element.SendKeys("Hello Selenium WebDriver!");

    element.Submit();
}
```

My code is working fine in IE now. You can follow this link [Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java)
Java and C# are the same. Hope it helps.

Comment: Could you share your code which have you tried as well??? it's `.exe` not `.zip`.. you need to extract this zip..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you’ve downloaded `IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.0.zip`, extract the zips to a local drive on your computer.

**Make sure to add the path to where you extracting the `IEDriverServer.exe`**

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"path\to\where you extracting the IEDriverServer");
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

**Note** :- I'm suggesting you download **32-bit IEDriverService.exe** because **64-bit IEDriverService.exe** is very very slow for execution.

Comment: I edited like:
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"E:\Yumy\Learn\DH\Kiem thu\IEDriverServer.exe");
But it don't run

Comment: @D.ÝNguyện is there any exception??

Comment: @D.ÝNguyện proivde only extracted  driver location as `WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"E:\Yumy\Learn\DH\Kiem thu")`.. no need to pass IEDriverServer.exe as well

Comment: The IE browser opened and displayed "The IE browser opened and displayed". And It still don't run test case

Comment: @D.ÝNguyện I think this is the problem of IE security setting follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java

Comment: Thank you so much. My code is working fine in IE now

Answer (score 0):

You have to Place the IEDriverServer.exe in the Bin directory in c#. I guess in Java you need to Add the path of the IEDriverServer.exe in the Path environment variables.