# Running parallel Protractor tests in Firefox and IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, protractor

I was able to successfully run a test in IE11 by tinkering with the settings following the accepted answer here:

[Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java)

I am trying to run it in parallel browsers. I managed to get Firefox + Chrome to work but not Firefox + IE11.

conf.js:

```
// parallel - firefox and ie11
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  multiCapabilities: [{
    browserName: 'firefox',
    firefoxPath: 'C:/Program Files/Mozilla Firefox/firefox.exe'
  }, {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    platform: 'ANY',
    version: '11'
  }],
  directConnect: true
}
```

Comment: "directConnect" option only works for chrome and firefox. Try removing that option.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `directConnect=true`. It's supported only for firefox & chrome. Checkout the below extract from [official Protractor documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/config.ts#L169)

> If true, Protractor will connect directly to the browser Drivers    *
>   at the locations specified by chromeDriver and firefoxPath. Only
>   Chrome    * and Firefox are supported for direct connect.

That was the reason why your tests were working for chrome & firefox and not on IE

Comment: Hi, removing `directConnect` ran IE successfully but failed in FF. Maybe running FF+IE in parallel is not possible?