# Internet Explorer not launched using selenium even though ignoreProtect mode settings are enabled

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

Sample Code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
caps['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True

browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=caps)
browser.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Internet Explorer is not launched and I am facing the below error :

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. Protected Mode settings are not the same for all zones. Enable Protected Mode must be set to the same value (enabled or disabled) for all zones.
```

I can not change the settings in the InternetExplorer. They are controlled by Admin.

I am stuck at this starting point only, can some one help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to launch IE browser using Selenium2 (Webdriver) with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: Depending on the version of the IE driver you’re using, the capabilities you’re sending across the wire will not work for the driver for ignoring Protected Mode settings. What happens if you use the `selenium.webdriver.ie.Options` class instead of hand-crafting your capabilities?

Answer (score 1):

To open `InternetExplorer` you need to implement the following **`Configurations`** :

1. On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the **`Protected Mode settings`** for each zone to be the same value. The value can be **on** or **off**, as long as it is the same for every zone. To set the Protected Mode settings, choose "Internet Options..." from the Tools menu, and click on the Security tab. For each zone, there will be a check box at the bottom of the tab labeled "Enable Protected Mode".
2. Additionally, **`Enhanced Protected Mode`** must be disabled for `IE 10 and higher`. This option is found in the `Advanced tab` of the `Internet Options` dialog.
3. The browser `zoom level` must be set to **`100%`** so that the native mouse events can be set to the correct coordinates.
4. For `Windows 10`, you also need to set `Change the size of text, apps, and other items` to **100%** in display settings.
5. For `IE 11` only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`**. For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE`**. Please note that the **`FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey`** may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a **`DWORD`** value named **iexplore.exe** with the value of **0**.

Now, you have to setup the  **`IEDriverServer`** binary with the following settings through **`DesiredCapabilities`**  :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

cap = DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
cap['ignoreProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
cap['nativeEvents'] = True
cap['ignoreZoomSetting'] = True
cap['requireWindowFocus'] = True
cap['INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS'] = True
browser = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=cap, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\IEDriverServer.exe')
browser.get('http://google.com/')
```

Comment: As my system is controlled by the Admin, i don't have the access to change the protected Mode settings in IE. Is there any possibility to overcome this step with alternate approach ?

Comment: My solution includes some code to overcome the issue you are facing with `protected Mode settings`. try the code and lets keep our figures crossed :)