# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session error with Selenium and IE11 using Java

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I'm trying to automate my test cases using Selenium with the following software applications.

- WebDriver 3.12.0
- InternetExplorerDriver3.150.1
- IE11 browser
- Java1.8.0.231

Here's my script to initialize the driver.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","driver path");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
System.out.println("Driver initialized.");
driver.get("application web url");
```

For the above script, I'm getting the below error message.

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session....
```

I have tried with different versions of drivers and selenium webdriver. But didn't workout. What could be the cause and how can I resolve it?

Could anyone give me your suggestions?

Thanks,
Karunagara Pandi G

Comment: This error can be occurred due to compatibility issue. make sure that Selenium web driver version, IE driver version, IE browser all are using the latest version. You can download the compatible version from this link . Ref:https://selenium.dev/downloads/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session....
```

...implies that the **IEDriverServer** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowsing Session** i.e. **InternetExplorer Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium WebDriver Client* version is **3.12.0** which is a bit older.
- Your *InternetExplorerDriver* version **3.150.1**.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.12.0* , *IEDriverServer v3.150.1*.

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *IEDriverServer* to [**IEDriverServer v3.141.59**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.141/) or [**IEDriverServer v3.150.0**](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.150/) level.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### tl; dr

- [Internet Explorer Protective mode setting and Zoom levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850465/internet-explorer-protective-mode-setting-and-zoom-levels/49851282#49851282)
- [Internet Explorer not launched using selenium even though ignoreProtect mode settings are enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020561/internet-explorer-not-launched-using-selenium-even-though-ignoreprotect-mode-set/48020684#48020684)
- [How does the registry entry HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\…\FEATURE_BFCACHE for InternetExplorerDriver solves the Internet Explorer 11 issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51600120/how-does-the-registry-entry-hkey-local-machine-feature-bfcache-for-internete/51929196#51929196)

Comment: Thank you Debanjan for the detailed response. :)