# Run Test With IE And Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I want to Run Automated Tests With IE11 and IEDriverServer=3.13, Selenium 3.13 my script work fine with chrome and Firefox, but with IE the code can't interact with elements and I have the following error:

```
déc. 25, 2018 4:57:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions 
findElement
AVERTISSEMENT: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.xpath: //* 
[@name='login'])
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Currently focused window has been 
closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for various reason, but in your case it is working fine n both chrome and Firefox. Probably the zoom level of your ie browser might be more or less than 100% or Downgrade ie driver version and test.

Thanks

Comment: yes i am using this answer :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952348/not-able-to-launch-ie-browser-using-selenium2-webdriver-with-java , but i still have many probléms with IE  like same xpath doesnt work:org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #nom

Comment: Can you Try with ie driver version 3.7 or 3.8. I am using the same for Selenium 3.13 and IE11. it is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your custom size:

driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
you can change your dimensions same as your requirements.

Comment: I have problem to choose the suitable IeDriver for selenium 3.13 and IE11 any idea?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.InternetExplorer.WebDriver/ follow this link you will find all details